# SQL Server - split record over multiple months into records by one month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have following table:

```
ID | user | from       | to         | loan
1  | BB   | 01/01/2016 | 01/05/2016 | 50
2  | AD   | 01/01/2016 | 01/03/2016 | 25
3  | AD   | 01/03/2016 | 17/05/2016 | 30
```

The `loan` in this table is monthly. So user BB earned 50 coins/month from 01/01/2016 to 01/05/2016. I want to split this into the following records:

```
 ID | user | from       | to         | loan
 1  | BB   | 01/01/2016 | 01/02/2016 | 50
 1  | BB   | 01/02/2016 | 01/03/2016 | 50
 1  | BB   | 01/03/2016 | 01/04/2016 | 50
 1  | BB   | 01/04/2016 | 01/05/2016 | 50
 2  | AD   | 01/01/2016 | 01/02/2016 | 25
 2  | AD   | 01/02/2016 | 01/03/2016 | 25
 3  | AD   | 01/03/2016 | 01/04/2016 | 30
 3  | AD   | 01/04/2016 | 01/05/2016 | 30
 3  | AD   | 01/05/2016 | 17/05/2016 | 30
```

Any ideas/suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: Either a recursive CTE or a calendar table that you join with your data

Comment: Why doesn't the record with an ID of 3 split into 3 records, (`01/03/2016 - 01/04/2016`, `01/04/2016 - 01/05/2016`, and `01/05/2016 - 17/05/2016`)?

Comment: @GarethD My bad, I missed a record over there. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(ID INT,[user] VARCHAR(100),[from] DATE,[to] DATE,loan INT);
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
 (1,'BB','01/01/2016','01/05/2016',50)
,(2,'AD','01/01/2016','01/03/2016',25)
,(3,'AD','01/03/2016','17/05/2016',30);

DECLARE @FirstDay DATE='01/01/2016';

WITH SomeNumbers AS --replace this with a values/tally/numbers/date table
(
    SELECT * FROM(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3)) AS t(Nr)
)


SELECT DISTINCT
       x.FirstOfMonth
      ,FittingData.*
FROM SomeNumbers
CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,SomeNumbers.Nr,@FirstDay) AS FirstOfMonth) AS x
CROSS APPLY(SELECT * FROM @Dummy AS d WHERE x.FirstOfMonth>=d.[from] AND x.FirstOfMonth<d.[to]) AS FittingData
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID,[from]
```

The result

```
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| FirstOfMonth | ID | user | from       | to         | loan |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-01-01   | 1  | BB   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-05-01 | 50   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-02-01   | 1  | BB   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-05-01 | 50   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-03-01   | 1  | BB   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-05-01 | 50   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-04-01   | 1  | BB   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-05-01 | 50   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-01-01   | 2  | AD   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-03-01 | 25   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-02-01   | 2  | AD   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-03-01 | 25   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-03-01   | 3  | AD   | 2016-03-01 | 2016-05-17 | 30   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2016-04-01   | 3  | AD   | 2016-03-01 | 2016-05-17 | 30   |
+--------------+----+------+------------+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ;WITH testtable(ID,[USER],[from],[to],loan)AS(
    SELECT 1,'BB',CONVERT(DATE,'01/01/2016'),CONVERT(DATE,'01/05/2016'),50 UNION all
    SELECT 2,'AD','01/01/2016','01/03/2016',25 UNION all
    SELECT 3 ,'AD','01/03/2016','01/05/2016',30
 )
 SELECT t.ID,t.[USER],DATEADD(d,sv.number,t.[FROM]) AS [From],dateadd(d,sv.number+1,t.[FROM]) AS [To],t.loan FROM testtable AS t
 INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values AS sv ON sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(d,t.[FROM],t.[TO])-1
```

```
ID          USER From       To         loan
----------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----------
1           BB   2016-01-01 2016-01-02 50
1           BB   2016-01-02 2016-01-03 50
1           BB   2016-01-03 2016-01-04 50
1           BB   2016-01-04 2016-01-05 50
2           AD   2016-01-01 2016-01-02 25
2           AD   2016-01-02 2016-01-03 25
3           AD   2016-01-03 2016-01-04 30
3           AD   2016-01-04 2016-01-05 30
```